# Why is width the first dimension in this code?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 14)) 

i = randint(0, len(X_train))
img = X_train[i]

ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax.set_title('Digit: {}'.format(y_train[i]), fontsize=16)

width, height = img.shape
thresh = img.max()/2.5
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        ax.annotate('{:2}'.format(img[x][y]), 
                    xy=(y,x),
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center',
                    color='white' if img[x][y]<thresh else 'black')
```

This code is from https://github.com/stefan-jansen/machine-learning-for-trading/blob/main/18_convolutional_neural_nets/02_digit_classification_with_lenet5.ipynb

I thought height should be the first dimension and I changed the code into

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 14)) 

i = randint(0, len(X_train))
img = X_train[i]

ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax.set_title('Digit: {}'.format(y_train[i]), fontsize=16)

height, width = img.shape
thresh = img.max()/2.5
for x in range(height):
    for y in range(width):
        ax.annotate('{:2}'.format(img[x][y]), 
                    xy=(y,x),
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center',
                    color='white' if img[x][y]<thresh else 'black')
```

They got the identical output, but I still don't understand why the author make the width the first dimension?

Comment: X loops over the height of the image in that code, just swap x and y everywhere to have it make sense.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thank you, I have edited this question and I have changed my code. I only changed the line ```xy=(x,y)``` into ```xy=(y,x)```, now they got the identical output. But I still don't understand why the author make the width the first dimension?

Comment: The author did not make the width the first dimension. The author just named the vertical dimension `x` and the horizontal one `y`. This is just about variable names, which are arbitrary but if you pick them right then the code is easier to read. The author also loops in the wrong order: if you swap the two loops (looping over first index in outer loop), the code will be more efficient.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Oh, I mean in his code it is ```width, height = img.shape``` but I think it should be ```height, width = img.shape```. I am sorry if my question is not important or wrong. I am new in deep learning.

Comment: This has nothing to do with deep learning. Indeed, they swapped `x` and `y` names, as well as `width` and `height` names. What the code calls `width` is the height of the image. I don't know why the author wrote things the way they did, but it makes no sense. In your code you can rename `x` and `y` as well, making `for y in range(height):` and `for x in range(width):`. That is more consistent with naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you very much, now the question is solved perfectly.